# Missing .NET 7 option in Azure Function template

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and want to create an Azure function using NET 7 isolated. However there is no NET 7 option at all:

[image]

So, how do I create an Azure function with NET 7?

Comment: Are you using VS 2022 Preview? I think it wasn't available in the stable version yet.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages

Comment: @juunas I am using stable, but now installing preview to check

Comment: @Skin Well, according to that it is stable, but guess that's more the Azure side of view than Visual Studio?

Comment: I think you can do this ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#override-a-default

Comment: found the solution, see my solution below :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the solution in the comments of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH6Ps1k2Nfg) Youtube video

> delete %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools and relauch your Visual Studio

worked fine for me (Visual Studio 2022 stable), now it looks like this :-)
[image]

Comment: Weird, but it worked in my VisualStudio 17.5.1. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for my VisualStudio 17.5.4. Thanks!!!

Comment: Confirmed that it works. No need to try to update Azure Function Core Tools. As long as you have v4 and have the latest Visual Studio Update, deleting the AzureFunctionsTools folder complety and re-launching Visual Studio brings the .NET 7 Isolated in the dropdown menu.

Comment: This actually worked, thanks

Comment: Yesterday, .NET 8 was released, yet the problem mentioned earlier still persists in Visual Studio 17.8.0. Fortunately, the solution provided earlier worked effectively. Thanks for that. However, upon loading Visual Studio, it displays '.NET 8 Isolated (Preview)'. To access the proper .NET 8 Isolated version, follow these steps in Visual Studio: go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Azure Functions, then 'Check for updates', and finally 'Download & Install' on the right side. This will update Azure functions to .NET 8 Isolated.

Comment: The fix provided by @manu above worked for me as well. I can now see .Net 8 Isolated in Visual Studio 2022